# Strip Characters in Jupyter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have what should be a simple problem. I have a lot of data which comes in the timestamp as below
I want to remove the values " +01" from the right hand side.

```
     Time
0 12/11/2021 09:26:02.001 +01
1 12/11/2021 09:26:02.021 +01
```

I am using the code below, but this also removes the .001 part of the first timestamp also

```
df=df.map(lambda x: x.rstrip(' +01'))
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: If every timestamp has it you could just strip the last 4 characters. stripped=nonstripped[:-4]. string.rstrip() takes a character list as argument and will remove all matching characters from the end of the string, it doesn't look at the pattern.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Jupyter. Please, remove it from the question and tags.

Comment: @joachimbf how does this work?

Comment: Python array slicing allows for getting a selection of an array if you know the indices you are interested in. array[:-4] gets all elements except the last 4 in the array. Strings can be treated as arrays of characters.

Comment: Yep.....this worked....thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rstrip` method deals with the provided strings as a list of characters to remove. It will remove **any** character (from the right side) that is within the string.

You can instead use regex:

```
import re
re.sub(r" \+01", "", a)
```